# Binding mouse to keyboard keys

Tags: mouse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I assign a middle button press to a specific key in my laptop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45203/how-can-i-assign-a-middle-button-press-to-a-specific-key-in-my-laptop)

Hi I have a logitech mx revolution mouse and am trying to bind some of its buttons to keyboard keys, following this guide:
http://www.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=95073

I found the keys on the keyboard and the curresponding buttons on the mouse, and mapped them as indicated, however the buttons still do not have any response when I press them. Am I missing something?

In /home/.xbindkeysrc I have:

"xdotool key Alt_L"
 b:13

"xdotool key Shift + Shift_L"
  b:15

Comment: Have a look at this question and answer for a possible solution: http://askubuntu.com/questions/45203/how-can-i-assign-a-middle-button-press-to-a-specific-key-in-my-laptop/72612#72612

Comment: Have you installed xdotool ? Try to type the xdotool in your terminal to check. If you get an error message, install it.